# How to run android x86 so file on linux?

Tags: android, linux, x86, shared-libraries, libc

I have an x86 so file built for Android (x86). How can I use this so file in Linux inside a java application? It says it needs LIBC version of libc.so, libz.so, libdl.so, libm.so.

Comment: Copy/paste the exact error messages.  I assume this is a `.so` shared library, not an executable?

Comment: yes it is a .so shared library. It says libc.so not found : LIBC version not found